# Vue Router Error

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Trying set up Vue Router. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Getting the error

`Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. (found in root instance)`

Again, I'm coming to Vue from React and while they are pretty similar there are small things that are different and there aren't as many Vue resources out there yet.

I'm using the Webpack template and using single file components. One thing I didn't completely understand was this part in the documentation

```
// 1. Define route components.
// These can be imported from other files
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
```

Is this just he same as me doing `import Foo from 'path/to/component/` ?

Anyway, thanks for any and all help!

Here is my `main.js` file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import QuizBuilder from '../src/components/QuizBuilder.vue'
import ResourceInfo from '../src/components/ResourceInfo.vue'

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  { path: '/info', component: ResourceInfo },
  { path: '/quiz-builder', component: QuizBuilder }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

My `index.html` looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Digestible</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do your QuizBuilder or ResourceInfo components have templates?

Comment: Yeah I used the webpack template generator so my `QuizBuilder.vue` and `ResourceInfo.vue` files each have `<template></template>`, `<script></script>`, and `<style></style>` sections.

Comment: see if this helps http://archive.forum.vuejs.org/topic/4399/vue-2-0-vue-warn-failed-to-mount-component-template-or-render-function-not-defined-found-in-root-instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have the components properly, you still need a small update.

When loading vue router as module system, the application should be initialized with the following way:

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: Ok. Yeah I did that and actually did `render: h => h('view-router')` and that seemed to solved it. Thanks!